# How can you reset variables to their original value in python?

Tags: python, variables

I am making a hangman game and I want to be able to reset the lives and score back to their original value (6&0). This code does not seem to work.

```
def newwords():
    newgamewords.append(input('Enter new word: '))
    print('Do you want to add any more words? yes or no?')
    answer=input()
    if answer == 'yes':
        newwords()
    else:
        while len(guessedletters) > 0 : guessedletters.pop()
        while len(displayletters) > 0 : displayletters.pop()
        lives = 6
        finalscore=0
         score
        gamewords[:] = newgamewords
        hangmangame()
```

Here is the code at the beginning of the game (these variables are not in any definition, i have made every variable in my code global just to be sure):

```
lives=6
score=0
```

Comment: That code works just fine; there must be another problem.

Comment: I suspect you are confusing locals with globals but we cannot tell with this little information.

Comment: Use constants to save your constant values. Assign these constant to your local variables and reset when needed

Comment: You might try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and post your whole code.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I wouldn't have thought codereview - the code's blatantly faulty (popping both lists on the else looks wrong - as well as other stuff) - so, the OP needs to re-write this and in doing so, hopefully be able to address a *specific* question. Until then - definitely not a real question...

Comment: @JonClements, my subtle point is that he needs a lot of help and this isn't the site for reviewing his entire code base.

Comment: @MarkTolonen my understanding of codereview was for working code that was asking for better ways to write it... this isn't working code - so I don't expect it would be that well received there...

Comment: @JonClements, Noted.  It's not a site I frequent.  Now I read the FAQ.

Comment: I understand it is faulty, but I am only a GCSE student who knows nothing about python and am trying to get help in anyway possible.

Comment: @user1949690 If any consolation - I think it's not a bad post! (not comparable to my "home work due tomorrow this is copy/paste of assignment - plz wr9 mez it). However, take it as a bit of a learning curve, and automatically put what you were asked to in the comments to this question (possibly with a bit more context) and specific question, and I'm sure it'll be much easier all around. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change a global variable, you have to declare them global or they will be considered a local variable.  Example:

```
lives = 6

def change():
    global lives
    lives = 0
```

Comment: Note though that this is the classic case of a global that should be a class member.